# Web based plugin architecture for simple user interfaces

Tags: plugins, primefaces

I have a web based application using Primefaces with a very basic plug-in like architecture. The configuration of these plug-ins was all handled with xml, which is not so user friendly system.

I would now like to allow for each plug-in to be configurable via the web application, what are my options?

I have looked into Portals and Portlets but that seems like a rather big change to my application and my plug-ins do not require such complex user interfaces, a textbox or two of configuration is more than enough.

Does anyone have any suggestions or advice and what would be the best route here?

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple page , per plugin that read the XML file, parse the option that you want to change , present it to the user with a simple interface, and save back the XML file.

Take care of the saving part and password-protect this page!